# Finding the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{4^{2n}(2n+1)}$

Tags: power-series

Could someone please give me a hand with the following series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{4^{2n}(2n+1)}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in these forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that :
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty \:}\frac{\left(-1\right)^nx^{2n+1}}{4^{2n}\left(2n+1\right)}$$
$$$$
Use the Ratio Test to compute the convergence interval :
$$\mathrm{Series\:Ratio\:Test:}$$
$$\mathrm{If\:there\:exists\:an\:}N\mathrm{\:so\:that\:for\:all\:}n\ge N,\:$$
$$a_n\ne 0\mathrm{\:and\:}\lim _{n\to \infty }|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=L:$$
$$\mathrm{If\:}L<1\mathrm{,\:then\:}\sum a_n\mathrm{\:converges}$$
$$\mathrm{If\:}L>1\mathrm{,\:then\:}\sum a_n\mathrm{\:diverges}$$
$$\mathrm{If\:}L=1\mathrm{,\:then\:the\:test\:is\:inconclusive}$$
$$$$
Therefore :
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\left|\frac{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}x^{2\left(n+1\right)+1}}{4^{2\left(n+1\right)}\left(2\left(n+1\right)+1\right)}}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^nx^{2n+1}}{4^{2n}\left(2n+1\right)}}\right|$$
$$$$
Compute :
$$L=\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\left|\frac{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}x^{2\left(n+1\right)+1}}{4^{2\left(n+1\right)}\left(2\left(n+1\right)+1\right)}}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^nx^{2n+1}}{4^{2n}\left(2n+1\right)}}\right|\right)$$
$$$$
Simplify :
$$\frac{\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}x^{2\left(n+1\right)+1}}{4^{2\left(n+1\right)}\left(2\left(n+1\right)+1\right)}}{\frac{\left(-1\right)^nx^{2n+1}}{4^{2n}\left(2n+1\right)}}:\quad -\frac{x^2\left(2n+1\right)}{16\left(2n+3\right)}$$
$$$$
Thus :
$$L=\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\left|-\frac{x^2\left(2n+1\right)}{16\left(2n+3\right)}\right|\right)$$
$$L=\left|-\frac{x^2}{16}\right|\cdot \lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\left|\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}\right|\right)$$
$$$$
We know that :
$$\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\left|\frac{2n+1}{2n+3}\right|\right)=1$$
$$$$
So :
$$L=\left|-\frac{x^2}{16}\right|\cdot \:1$$
$$$$
Simplify :
$$L=\frac{\left|x\right|^2}{16}$$
$$\mathrm{The\:power\:series\:converges\:for\:}L<1$$
$$\frac{\left|x\right|^2}{16}<1$$
$$$$
Find the radius of convergence :
$$\frac{\left|x\right|^2}{16}<1:\quad \left|x\right|<4$$
$$\mathrm{Radius\:of\:convergence\:is}\:4$$
$$$$
Find the interval of convergence :
$$\frac{\left|x\right|^2}{16}<1\quad :\quad -4<x<4$$
$$\mathrm{Check\:the\:interval\:end\:points}:\quad x=-4:\mathrm{converges},\:x=4:\mathrm{converges}$$
$$\mathrm{Interval\:of\:convergence\:is}\:-4\le \:x\le \:4$$
$$$$
Final answer is :
$$\mathrm{Radius\:of\:convergence\:is}\:4,\:\:\mathrm{Interval\:of\:convergence\:is}\:-4\le \:x\le \:4$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{∞} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{4^{2n}(2n+1)}$, so $f'(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{∞} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{4^{2n}}$ so the derivative converges iff $|x|< 4$. In this case $f'(x) =\frac{-x^2}{x^2+16}$. Integrating it you will get that $f(x) =4\tan^{-1}(\frac{x}{4}) -x$. You just need to analyse the limit cases for the serie with Leibniz's criterion